Python Comtypes not converting .doc to Pdf
I have a Python Script to convert old .doc files to Pdf made from this answer. The new .docx format is no problem but the .doc doesn't work. I don't get any error messages but it doesn't convert to Pdf either. I debugged it and the paths seem fine, it executes the doc.SaveAs() Function which seems to do nothing.
Code:
import comtypes.client
import time
import os

def convert_doc_to_pdf(doc_path, pdf_path):
    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
    word.Visible = False
    try:
        doc = word.Documents.Open(doc_path)
        doc.SaveAs(pdf_path, FileFormat=17)  # 17 is format for Pdf
        doc.Close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to convert {doc_path} to PDF. Error: {e}")
    finally:
        word.Quit()


def convert_docs_to_pdf(directory_path):
    doc_files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory_path) if file.endswith(('.docx', '.doc'))]
    for doc_file in doc_files:
        doc_path = os.path.join(directory_path, doc_file)
        pdf_path = os.path.splitext(doc_path)[0] + '.pdf'
        abs_doc_path = os.path.abspath(doc_path)
        abs_pdf_path = os.path.abspath(pdf_path)

        convert_doc_to_pdf(abs_doc_path, abs_pdf_path)
        time.sleep(5) # Converting multiple .docx files without sleep crashes

def main():
    directory_path = r"TravelReports"
    print("Converting Word to Pdf:")
    convert_docs_to_pdf(directory_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    

Tried debugging, tried different .doc Documents etc.
Thank you, I'm still a junior trying his best
